# Return items one by one from groovy list

Tags: groovy

Im pretty new to Groovy and I'm struggling a little. I have got a List and I want to return the items in the list 1 by 1 each time I call the function

```
def list = [
    "blog1",
    "blog2",
    "blog3"
]
// Result variable for storing loop results.
def result = ''
// Closure to fill result variable with value.
def createResult = {
    if (!it) {  // A bit of Groovy truth: it == 0 is false
        result = '0'
    } else {
        result += it
    }
}

// Groovy for-each loop.
for (i in list) {
    createResult(i)
}
return result
```

Now I get back the following value: blog1blog2blog3

I would like to see:

First call of this code return blog 1, 2nd call of the function return blog 2 etc.

How to solve this?

Comment: Can you explain the problem better?  I can't see from the code above what you are expecting to get back or see...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're describing an `Iterator`

If you want a closure that wraps an iterator and handles the end of the list without an exception, you could do:

```
def closure = { ->
    def i = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'].iterator();
    { -> i.hasNext() ? i.next() : null }
}

def clos = closure()

println clos()
println clos()
println clos()
println clos()
```

Which prints:

```
item1
item2
item3
null
```

Not 100% sure that's what you want though, it's hard to tell from the question...

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
result += it
```

to:

```
result = it
```

But better to use iterator:

```
def iter = list.iterator()
def getListValue = {iterator ->
    iterator.hasNext() ? iterator.next() : null
}
def createResult = getListValue.curry(iter)

println createResult()
println createResult()
println createResult()
```